# SSH RSA and ED25519 keys passphrase issue

Tags: macos, ssh, rsa

I have two types of keys based on RSA and ED25519 keys.

however when I do

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 <server>
```

I get prompted to enter passphrase for RSA based key first then get asked for ED25519 key passphrase

```
Enter passphrase for key '~/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '~/.ssh/id_ed25519':
```

My both public keys are in authorized keys of the server.

What would be the reason for this

Also

```
~/.ssh/config
```

doesn't any settings and is totally empty.

Comment: Do you have the corresponding id_rsa.pub & id_ed25519.pub files as well?

Answer (score 0):

The `-i` option of `ssh` specifies an *extra* private key to use.

To prevent `ssh-agent` from providing more identities, you can add the `-o "IdentitiesOnly=yes"` option to your command, but the default keys inside your `~/.ssh` directory might still be tried.

The sure way to only use a specific key is to make an entry for the given host in the `~/.ssh/config` file.